# Confused with the outcome of this list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a `texts` which is a list of sentences, and this piece of code is supposed to remove numbers in the texts:

```
[''.join(c for c in x if c not in '0123456789') for x in texts]
```

And it works.

Now, `x in texts` means every sentence in the `texts` list. And `c for c in x` would mean every word in each `x` sentence? I am confused because something like this does not work:

```
[c for c in x for x in texts]
# or
[c for c in (x for x in texts)]
```

to create a list of every word from each sentence.

Doesn't `[''.join(c for c in x if c not in '0123456789') for x in texts]` first split the sentences into words? The more I think about it, the more I get confused. I would love clarification.

Comment: if you want to split to get words use `texts.split()`. But the `if c not in` won't work unless those words are numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for c in x` where x is a string, means to take each char of the string, not each word.

In other words, strings are sequences of chars.

Comment: Ahh right. I see. But then why doesn't `[c for c in x for x in texts]` or `[c for c in (x for x in texts)]`  work? It should give me a list of all the characters?

Comment: @Huzo the syntax is wrong. When using dual list comprehension you have to reverse the for: `[c for x in texts for c in x]`